# Does this ruby code count as a recursive function?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, terminology

I am reading about recursion. One of the exercises is to write a recursive function to sum the numbers in an array. I should not use `Array#sum` to do this. I wrote this to imitate recursion:

```
def recursive_sum(list)
  if list == []
    return 0
  else
    return list.shift + recursive_sum(list)
  end
end

recursive_sum [1,2,3,4]
# => 10
```

"A recursive function/method calls itself." This is clear, and it seems this function does call itself. But I am not sure whether this counts as a recursive function because I used `shift` method in it.

Comment: Yes, it is a recursive function.

Comment: Why do you think you might not be allowed to use `shift`?

Comment: Yes, it's recursive, but consider `def recursive_sum(list); first, *rest = list; rest.empty? ? first : first + recursive_sum(rest); end`. Note if `first, *rest = [1,2,3]`, then `first #=> 1` and `rest #=> [2,3]`.

Comment: @Stefan. I considered I should use more basic operation(such as index) to achieve this. It turns out that thought was wrong.

Comment: You could consider using methods that don't modify their receiver (as suggested by Cary Swoveland above). But that doesn't affect the "recursiveness" of your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would call this a recursive function  for exactly the reason you already mentioned: *"A recursive function/method calls itself."*

That the method calls `shift` doesn't harm. In fact, it calls other methods too - like `if`, `==`, `+`

You were not allowed to call any other method but only to call the method itself than the method would not be able to do anything useful.

```
def foo
  foo
end
```

Calling that recursive method would raise a `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)`.

Comment: Nitpicking, but `if` is not a method.